# Schengen visa for two consecutive trips with one day break?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-refusals, multiple-entry

I am from a Southeast Asian country and study in England. I want to travel to Europe this October, first from 1st October to 10th October, then come back from Madrid to England on 10th, go again to Greece on the evening of 11th October.

I applied at Spanish consulate in London and it may take 4 weeks until I get my passport back. I just want to ask if it is possible for me to get a multiple entry Schengen visa that covers both trips? Worse, can I get refused by having one day break in England? In my application, I put that I will come back England for one day break before my second part. I was not thinking my visa application would have problem (I did have one Schengen visa before from Italy and I travelled according to my plan); however, as much as I read from this forum, I start worrying that I might get my visa refused because of unclear reason to reenter the Schengen area.

Please anyone has some experience, can you tell me your thinking on this? Should I get the visa refused as a whole? Or would I get the visa rejected for the second trip?

My background is as follows:

1. Nationality: a Southeast Asia, study in England with a Tier 4 visa
2. travel history: had another tier 4 visa before, plus a Schengen visa from Italy for 30 days, visa to visit Turkey for 6 months (not mentioned in my application)
3. Sufficient finances (total £7000), booked all hotels and night buses for two trips plus all travelling tickets, even trains and night buses (I will travel by sleep train twice).
4. Mentioning clearly in the application that my trip has two parts, separate by one (two) days (from 10th to 11th in England). But I didn't explain why (it is just I want to come back to England from Spain and go to Greece from London, just purely my preference and I want to recharge myself).
5. In Greece I will join with a friend who has a Schengen visa already and travel with them. However I dint mention the friend in my application because I don't want to get it complicated (because they are not in the UK at the moment and they have a Schengen visa already). In my flight tickets, the name of my friend also appears.

Comment: They will not refuse simply because you are breaking up your visit into two parts. They will examine the premise and see if it makes sense. You didn't include anything about your premise. Alternatively, is this a case of '[post-submission anxiety](http://www.visajourney.com/forums/topic/91153-another-user-with-post-submission-anxiety-evidence-question/)'? That's very normal. But if your app is already in the pipeline, what do you want people to say? Everything will be OK? Try and cancel it? Please edit your question to get very specific.   Close voting as 'unclear'

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link, I have edited my post with additional background. I just want to ask if anyone has experience and please can say something that may help me to calm my anxiety down. Because it takes 4 weeks to get my passport back, I just feel if someone says something either good or bad, I will have a better preparation when collecting the results. And obviously, will think about it less in the 4 weeks. Thank you and please don't close. Let me know if I should provide any information.

Comment: You haven't said how long you are planning to stay in Greece. It should not lead to a refusal but if the stay is longer than your time in Spain, it could prompt the Spanish consulate to issue a visa covering only the first part of your trip or to decline to process the application and to refer you to the Greek consulate.

Comment: Hi, I will say in Greece for 5 days, then I will go to Italy for another 5 days before heading back to England. In total, I stay in Spain for 10 days so that's why I applied for a Spanish Schengen visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will not refuse a visa because of this. If there is no other reason to refuse the visa, the worse I can see happening is that you would get a single-entry visa for Spain valid until the 10th of October. It would make the second part of the trip difficult to organise but you could still at least do the first part and would not have a refusal on your record.

At the end of the day, the decision will depend on some things you haven't mentioned and a refusal is always a possibility but the elements you did list (status in the UK, finances, previous travels) seem to make you a low-risk applicant. So if there is nothing unusual about the rest of your application, you are very likely to get what you need. Some people in your situation even get a one-year multiple-entry visa without asking for it.

Finally, the Schengen regulations make allowance for two-entry visas, originally intended for people who want to go to the UK in the middle of a trip to the Schengen area. That's not exactly your situation but the Spanish consulate could also use that if they are nervous about issuing a multiple-entry visa.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, it does help me feel better. I saw that you had another insight in my other topic (the one in which I worried if I arrived in Greece at 23:59 on 11th and said in the application that I would stay overnight at the airport to catch an early flight to Santorini at 7:00 12th. Do you think combining these two topics will make the refusal elements? You also mentioned that there are some things that I haven't mention, could you please let me know what kinds of the things? Thank you!!

Comment: @Thien Confusing plans are less than ideal but I would not worry just yet. Legally speaking, that's not a reason to refuse a visa either. I cannot provide any guarantees, though, a strange decision is always possible and as others already commented, there isn't much you can do and you will have to wait for the final decision to know.

Comment: Thank you very much. At least talking to somebody does help me feel better. I would not worry now as as you said, there shouldn't be any legal reason to refuse (same as the officer at the Spanish consulate , he said it would be fine but he wouldn't be sure because others make decision, not him). Thanks very much for the talking. I really appreciate.